# Not listening on configured UseUrls and launchsettings.json port

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I am suddenly unable to configure the port from which to listen on.  The default is now kicking:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

I want to be using 6677.

Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:6677/")
                .UseKestrel();
        });
```

launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "local"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:6677;http://localhost:6677"
    }
  }
}
```

I can confirm that I am using the correct profile because "local" is being parsed.

What have I done?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because I'm injecting an IConfiguration implementation into services:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"config.{environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: false)
    .Build();

services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
```

The config items have absolutely nothing to do with URLs, but I guess I have overridden something.

Comment: how did you end up fixing this?